# Momentjs unable to make diff of two dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hi I have problem with making diff between two dates using moment.

Here is my code

```
let data = localStorage.getItem("context");
let a = moment(data.updated_at).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');
let b = moment().format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');
console.log(b.diff(a));
```

I need to compare actual date with date from local storage which is saved in format `DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss`. I try `b.diff(a)` but it returns me error that diff is not a function.
What am I doing wrong please

I try this:

```
 let data = localStorage.getItem("context");
        let a = moment(data.updated_at,'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');
        let b = moment(data.updated_at,'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');
        let c = a.diff(b,'minutes');
        console.log(
           c
        );
```

This returned NaN  so idk what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am stupid... error was that data was in JSON.... So i have to parse it

```
JSON.parse(data);}
```

Comment: can't yet. I will when it will be possible

Answer (score 2):

`moment.format` returns a string but you need a moment instance to do the diff. Parse the localStorage input like this `moment(data.updated_at, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');` to get that.